# Is there any way to view a file live in html?

Tags: html

For example, if a file is updated while someone is viewing the page, automatically display this update, instead of requiring a refresh.

I want to make sure before I start JavaSripting to pull in the file on a interval and append it. Unless I'm mistaking, I don't think this can be done, but I'm just checking, just in case.

Comment: Unless you code the page to specifically go back to the server and request the latest file, you are correct, this is not "standard behaviour" for HTML

Answer (score 0):

No. HTML is for structuring a document. Without a refresh, there is no way for HTML to change its contents.

Comment: As I figured, ok I'll start the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a markup language related to SGML for creating structure and formatting in a web page. To achieve interaction beyond the initial request and response, you must utilize a programming language, not a document markup language. JS, possibly with some AJAX, is your subject matter. Good luck.